# max-width 100% для img на резиновом сайте. Дробные пиксели

Tags: html, css

Как можно решить проблему с изображениями, у которых `max-width: 100%`, на резиновом сайте?

Практически всегда у них значения ширины и высоты получаются с дробными значениями (например: `234.34` пикселей), из-за чего они становятся мутными.

Comment: Дробные значения у ширины изображений будут всегда, если у их контейнеров ширины задана в %

Comment: если img задано inline использовать srcset https://webref.ru/html/img/srcset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело не в дробных пикселях, даже если сделать их целыми, изображение будет все равно мутным из-за низкой плотности пикселей при его масштабировании.

Увеличите плотность пикселей в изображении минимум на 1.5x - 2x от того разрешения, который браузер выводит на экране. То есть, если у вас базовые размеры для экрана со стандартной плотностью пикселей 200x200, то потребуется изображение 400x400 для сохранения четкости на retina-экранах с повышенной плотностью пикселей.

Comment: Дело не в ретина. На обычном дисплеи оно немного мутное. Хотя оно реально большего размера, чем блок (там блок около 300 пикс, а изображение 450 пикс.).

Comment: @ЕвгенийВоробьев Так и должно быть, если на обычном дисплее изображение немного больше своего контейнера. Для четкости увеличите кратность изображения ровно в 2x (т.е. в вашем блоке должно быть изображение к 600 пикс.)